# R data analysis - qqplot - Error msg: unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'

Tags: r

I am facing an error message when calling function `qqplot` in car package. Here is details:

I use `lm` to do linear analysis for a data-set. And I want to check this model if it is good enough. Then I use `qqplot` in car package. Unfortunately, it returns an error message saying:

> Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") :unimplemented
>   type 'list' in 'greater'.

Could someone help me on this ? Cause I followed the steps in the book named "R in Action", but it didn't return the expected result.

Code:

```
library(car)
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77[,c('Murder','Population','Illiteracy',
                                'Income','Frost')])
mur <- lm(Murder~Population+Illiteracy+Income+Frost,states)
qqplot(mur)
```

Answer (score 2):

The function would be `qqPlot` from `library(car)`

```
library(car)
qqPlot(mur)
```

[image]