# R - qqplot - Error msg: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'

Tags: r

I'm facing an error message when using "qqplot" of package "car".

Code:

```
a = c(24,35,67,45,43,37,86,87,53,33,67,98)
b = c(34,67,42,78,42,79,43,77,43,67,34,78)
lm(a~b)
qqplot(lm(a~b))
```

> Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : 
>     unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'

There is a similar question already, but with no helpful answer.

[R data analysis - qqplot - Error msg: unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38674646/10919966)

Could someone help me?

Comment: The answer from Naveen is perfect. And the answer in the question mentioned above is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are looking for a function from `car` package, it is `qqPlot` and not `qqplot`.

Can you try `qqPlot(lm(a~b))`. This will return the below plot.

**Plot:**

[image]